# Integer not echoing via php

Tags: php, switch-statement, echo

I have a switch built in to set variables based on a `$_POST['x'];`

my echo test works on all the variables but one, and i cannot seem to find out why:

```
switch ($jobType) {
    case "pp":
        $jobType = "Pick Pocket"; //echo works 'Pick Pocket'
        $success = rand(1,100); //echo works - random numbers 1-100
        $threshold = 0; //echo works - '0'
        $money = rand(0-100); //changed to rand(0,100) and it works
        echo $money;
        break;
}
```

the echos I named work both inside the `case` and outside the `switch` except for `$money`. Any ideas what I am missing?

UPDATED --

> switching from `1-100` to `1,100` worked - thanks everyone!

Comment: typo error, `$money = rand(0-100);` . You missed `,` in between 1 and 100. **Correction:**  `$money = rand(0,100);`

Comment: I put it back with `//comments`. I updated it that way because I couldn't select an answer yet (time limits and all)

Comment: also not sure of the downvotes? Anyone wanna suggest something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$money = rand(0-100);
```

it's not `0-100` should be `0,100`

Answer (score 2):

I believe you use the rand function incorrectly. Try replacing the dash with a coma:

```
$money = rand(0, 100);
```

From php.net: `int rand ( int $min , int $max )`

Also you might wanna check what value you're actually getting. I don't believe it's an integer:

```
$money = rand(0-100);
var_dump($money);
```

I get NULL in this case and a warning: `WARNING rand() expects exactly 2 parameters, 1 given...`